# sql query to match between 2 columns

Tags: sql

Please help me to match between 2 table with different prefix, tables are as follows:

Table-A

```
Country Prefix  Price
Albania 3554249 xx
```

Table-B

```
Country Prefix  Price
Albania 3554    xx
```

Comment: Have you written any code yourself? Please share/post your code and let others know what problems are you facing. Also tag the database name you are working on.

Comment: what do you mean by match ? elaborate with an example.. so we will know

Answer (score 0):

Try a join:

```
Select *
From Table-A A, Table-B B
Where A.Country=B.Country
```

This matches the two tables on country. If you want to match on price too just add

```
And A.Price=B.Price
```

To the end

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from tablea a, tableb b
where a.prefix like (tableb.prefix || '%')
```

You may need to trim prefix on both tables if it's a char type:

```
where trim(a.prefix) like (trim(tableb.prefix) || '%')
```

Comment: Using an explicit `join` operator should be preferred over the old, outdated implicit joins in the `where` clause